# Insert row in a table in certain position

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a table, the first row of which is from the code below

```
                <tbody id="addRow">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" id="firstNameLabel">First Name:</td>
                    <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personArray[0].firstName, new { id = "firstName" })</td>
                    <td align="right" id="middleInitialLabel">Middle Initial:</td>
                    <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personArray[0].middleInitial, new { id = "middleInitial" })</td>
                    <td align="right" id="lastNameLabel">Last Name:</td>
                    <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personArray[0].lastName, new { id = "lastName" })</td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="addRow('0')" value="Add" id="addButton0" /></td>
                </tr>
```

When the "Add" button is clicked, a new row is inserted. However, the row is inserted at the BOTTOM of the table. How can I place the row immediately following the first row?

Javascript:

```
        function addRow(index) {

        $('#addButton' + index).attr("disabled", true);

        var counter = ++index;

        var content = `<tr><td align="right">First Name:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input id="personArray_${counter}__firstName" name="personArray[${counter}].firstName" type="text" value=""></td>
                        <td align="right">Middle Initial:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input id="middleInitial" name="personArray[${counter}].middleInitial" type="text" value=""></td>
                        <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input id="lastName" name="personArray[${counter}].lastName" type="text" value=""></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-xs valid" id="addButton${counter}" onclick="addRow('${counter}')" value="Add" aria-invalid="false"></td></tr>`;

        $('#addRow').append(content);


    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
function addRow(index) {

  $('#addButton' + index).attr("disabled", true);

  var counter = ++index;

  var content = `<tr><td align="right">First Name:</td>
                  <td align="left"><input id="personArray_${counter}__firstName" name="personArray[${counter}].firstName" type="text" value=""></td>
                  <td align="right">Middle Initial:</td>
                  <td align="left"><input id="middleInitial" name="personArray[${counter}].middleInitial" type="text" value=""></td>
                  <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
                  <td align="left"><input id="lastName" name="personArray[${counter}].lastName" type="text" value=""></td>
                  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-xs valid" id="addButton${counter}" onclick="addRow('${counter}')" value="Add" aria-invalid="false"></td></tr>`;

  //$('#addRow').append(content);

  $(content).insertAfter($("#addRow > tr").eq(index-1)); // Key line
```

};

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla JS solution. You can use [`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to direct the position of the new content relative to a specific element.

I've selected the first `tr` in the `tbody` and am putting the new content after the end of that row.

```
document.querySelector('#addRow > tr')
        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('tbody tr:first-child').after(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question you asked: You use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) on `$('#addRow tr:first')`:

```
$('#addRow tr:first').after(content);
```

**However**, the correct way to do this is to split the table into a [`thead`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#elementdef-thead) (probably with rows containing [`th`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#elementdef-th) rather than `td` elements) and `tbody`:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <td align="right" id="firstNameLabel">First Name:</td>
    <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personArray[0].firstName, new { id = "firstName" })</td>
    <td align="right" id="middleInitialLabel">Middle Initial:</td>
    <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personArray[0].middleInitial, new { id = "middleInitial" })</td>
    <td align="right" id="lastNameLabel">Last Name:</td>
    <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personArray[0].lastName, new { id = "lastName" })</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="addRow('0')" value="Add" id="addButton0" /></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="addRow">
```

Then you'd just use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) on the `tbody`.

```
$('#addRow').prepend(content);
```

Comment: `thead` is definitely the way to go overall.